# .NET 5 ef CLI toolinstallation not found

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have

- .NET SDK (5.0.201)
- dotnet-ef (version '5.0.4')
- on Debian Linux

When I run any dotnet ef command, like `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` or `dotnet ef database update` I receive the following error message:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

`dotnet-ef` is installed, if I run `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`, it says:

```
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
```

Funny thing is that this error does not happen always. There are days I do not see it at all, and there are days I can not get rid of it. This is happening since I have upgraded from .NET Core 3.1 to .Net 5.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

**Update**

I have found a workaround that temporarily solves the problem. Run:

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Then log out and log in again.

**Update 2**

An other workaround is to install the tool locally:

```
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You can log an issue here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/new/choose

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken Possible, but then I think it is not an EF Core, but and CLI/SDK bug.

Comment: Good point, however logging it there may help to identify if specific or general

Comment: I just had the exact same thing happen to me on Ubuntu 20.04 and the workaround also worked. I guess it is a bug/issue

Comment: Still broken on 23.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem still occurs in .Net 6. I have found the following permanent bypass:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
dotnet-ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet-ef database update
```

Note that I call the dotnet-ef executable directly and not through the dotnet command.